# Trying to import dictionary to work with from a url; 'unicode' object not callable

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new to coding and have searched as best I can to find out how to solve this before asking.

I'm trying to pull information from poloniex.com REST api, which is in JSon format I believe. I can import the data, and work with it a little bit, but when I try to call and use the elements in the contained dictionaries, I get "'unicode' object not callable". How can I use this information? The end goal with this data is to pull the "BTC: "(volume)" for each coin pair and test if it is <100, and if not, append it to a new list.

The data is presented like this or you can see yourself at https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume:

```
{"BTC_LTC":{"BTC":"2.23248854","LTC":"87.10381314"},"BTC_NXT":{"BTC":"0.981616","NXT":"14145"}, ... "totalBTC":"81.89657704","totalLTC":"78.52083806"}
```

And my code I've been trying to get to work with currently looks like this(I've tried to iterate the information I want a million different ways, so I dunno what example to give for that part, but this is how I am importing the data):

```
returnvolume = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/public?command=return24hVolume'))
coinvolume = json.loads(returnvolume.read())
coinvolume = dict(coinvolume)
```

No matter how I try to use the data I've pulled, I get an error stating:

"unicode' object not callable."

I'd really appreciate a little help, I'm concerned I may be approaching this the wrong way as I haven't been able to get anything to work, or maybe I'm just missing something rudimentary, I'm not sure.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Could you post the full traceback of the error you're getting with the code you've provided? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Try `pprint` module to display loading result.

Comment: I try to just print the contained dictionaries using: for items in coinvolume: print items('BTC')

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): TypeError: 'unicode' object not callable

Comment: @nickhardin, for me your code produces 100 dictionary items `{u'USDT_REP': {u'USDT': u'223942.75600344', u'REP': u'9087.87273062'}, ...`. If you want to only get `'BTC'` values try: `for _, item in coinvolume.iteritems():
    try:
        print item['BTC']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    except TypeError:
        print item`, works for me, i get 100 floats like `264.692641731`, `450.08155123`, ... `2269.26709902`

Comment: @downshift Thanks, that seems to be working in the right direction, however when I try to replace the last line (print item) with (if int(item) < 100: print item) to attempt to compare the value to 100 and return only the ones over 100, I still receive all the items no matter the value.

Comment: so you want to filter the dictionary to only get items less than 100?

Comment: Yes, ultimately to del the dictionary containing the value from the list of dictionaries.

Comment: My apologies if I'm not super clear, I am trying..

Comment: no worries, your fine. Maybe try this: `d = {};

for k, v in coinvolume.items():
    try:
        if float(v['BTC']) < 100:
            d[k] = v;
    except KeyError:
        d[k] = v;
    except TypeError:
        if v < 100:
            d[k] = k`. Sorry if it's difficult to read, we cannot format code in comments. For me it produces a new dictionary, `d`, that has 61 entries

Comment: Dang, you rock! Thank you so much! Even for being pretty new to this, I spent way to much time on that one issue, and this will help me tons to work more with polo's api in the future.

Comment: Actually, I may have spoken too soon, it appears when I print d, I still see coins with 'BTC' volumes under 100 included. However, it seems the included dictionaries are all under 100, so I just swapped the < signs for > instead, and it's good to go, Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to another user, downshift, I have discovered the answer!

```
d = {}

for k, v in coinvolume.items(): 
    try: 
        if float(v['BTC']) > 100: 
            d[k] = v
    except KeyError:
        d[k] = v
    except TypeError:
        if v > 100:
            d[k] = k
```

This creates a new list, d, and adds every coin with a 'BTC' volume > 100 to this new list.

Thanks again downshift, and I hope this helps others as well!